# Using a custom JSON format for rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

In a rails app I have an action that returns a json string. It looks something like this:

```
if exist_user
    format.json { render json: {:msg => 'has this user'}}
else
```

but rails show error:too few arguments

How do I render custom json string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have `respond_to` block, otherwise it doesn't know the format to send back.

```
respond_to do |format|
  if exist_user
    format.json { render json: {:msg => 'has this user'} }
  else
  end
end
```

Check out this for more detail, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html

Answer (score 1):

```
if exist_user
    format.json { render :json => {:msg => 'has this user'} }
else
```